# how to find the installed plugins in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, adt

I am developing Android application in Eclipse IDE-ADT.Here i cannot create Dynamic Web project. How can I do it. And how to find the installed plugin in eclipse.

Comment: [Eclipse FAQ: How do I find out what plug-ins have been installed?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_out_what_plug-ins_have_been_installed%3F)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Eclipse :
Goto Help
Click on **Install New Software...**
In opened dialog click on **Already Installed** link in below.
[image]

Comment: I checked  the installation,there i have only find ADT package.Is this enough?

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Eclipse** -> **About Eclipse** -> and click **Installation details** -> and click **Plug-ins**